# Error When Update To Hirsute Hippo

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, software-center

I Want To Update My System From Focal Fossa ( LTS ) To Hirsute Hippo ( Normal ), But I Found Some Error :

```
root@localhost:~# do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1268 kB]
Fetched 1269 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
authenticate 'hirsute.tar.gz' against 'hirsute.tar.gz.gpg'
extracting 'hirsute.tar.gz'

Reading cache
lspci: /sys/bus/pci/devices: No such file or directory

Checking package manager


A fatal error occurred

Please report this as a bug and include the files
/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log and /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log in
your report. The upgrade has aborted.
Your original sources.list was saved in
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-z3e__fxr/hirsute", line 8, in
<module>
sys.exit(main())

File
"/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-z3e__fxr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py",
line 236, in main
if app.run():

File
"/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-z3e__fxr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py",
line 2024, in run
return self.fullUpgrade()

File
"/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-z3e__fxr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py",
line 1794, in fullUpgrade
if not self.prepare():

File
"/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-z3e__fxr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py",
line 415, in prepare
self._sshMagic()

File
"/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-z3e__fxr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py",
line 274, in _sshMagic
is_child_of_process_name("sshd")):

File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-z3e__fxr/DistUpgrade/utils.py",
line 108, in is_child_of_process_name
with open(stat_file) as stat_f:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'/proc/16380/stat'


root@localhost:~#
```

How Can I Update To Hirsute Hippo From Focal Fossa? ( I Get Guide From https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-ubuntu-20-04-20-10-to-21-04/amp )

Comment: Ubuntu has two upgrade paths; (1) upgrade via every release, ie. 20.04 to 20.10, or (2) upgrade from one LTS to the next LTS **after** the .1 release has come out, ie. 20.04 will upgrade to 22.04.1.  You're outside of QA tested upgrade paths; though CI tests are always performed (assuming no 3rd party packages are included).  For best results you should remove 3rd party packages then re-try; though I suspect you've made python3 changes that need to be undone. You can examine the Mainlog.txt & Aptlog.txt for more specific details on your issue

Comment: It may be simpler to perform a fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

do-release-upgrade needs the "lspci" command.
That command can be found in the "pciutils" apt package

Try to install that package :

`root@localhost:~# apt install pciutils`

and run the do-release-upgrade command again (it worked for me)

`root@localhost:~# do-release-upgrade`

Comment: With the "pciutils" package, please find out why you were not able to access to the /sys/bus/pci/devices directory with a root account on your system. if the error (running "do-release-upgrade") is persistant.

Comment: -> If you are in a container / sub-system / protected environment, you might not have appropriate permissions (for good reasons).